# Set ImageButton text from the code?

Tags: android, imagebutton

In examples found on the net I saw that the text is set from XML file only. I need to attach the text from another View, and I tried to find any setter that I can use to set text to `ImageButton`. I didn't succeed. I even tried using this

```
<ImageButton
       android:background="#ffffff"
       android:text="setText()"
       />
```

hoping that I can use setText() in the code, but it did not work as well.

How can I set the text for `ImageButton` programmatically?

Thanks
PS. This is a custom ImageView which inherits `ImageView`.

Comment: You say that this is a custom ImageButton, please show us how you declare it.

Comment: I cannot show the code as it my company's code and I am not allowed to share it. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageButtons can't have text (or, at least, `android:text` isn't listed in its [attributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)).  It looks like you need to use Button (and look at `drawableTop` or `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,int,int,int)`).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set text to `ImageButton` because it has no method as `setText()` or `android:text` property.

Here is workaround, using a `Button` and `android:drawableTop` / `Left` / `Right` or `Bottom` like this :

```
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon" android:text="Button"
android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:textSize="11sp"
android:layout_margin="1sp" />
```